# Git Subtree Push

Tags: git

Up until a day ago, the following line worked just fine to push the "dist" directory to staging:

```
 git subtree push --prefix dist origin staging
```

Just the other day, git returned " Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"

So I tried:

```
 git push origin `git subtree split --prefix dist staging` :origin --force
```

Which  returns "fatal: cc2e4771aca6ed37b740c0225a10ae1fade9f296 cannot be resolved to branch."

I'm lost...any idea on how to force this push?

Comment: Are you collaborating with others?  Could you legitimately be behind locally and need to update?  If so, maybe force is the wrong choice here, and you just need to get up-to-date locally.

Comment: No, no collaboration.

Comment: I cheated and deleted the remote branch and pushed again.